# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('1')

Tags: mysql, funciones, mysql-cursores-anidados, funciones-mysql

## Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('1')' at line 1

Buenos días resulta que tengo que realizar la siguiente ejercicio.

Para cada cliente(nombre y apellidos) mostrar el número de factura de mayor importe y el de menor (usando funciones previamente creadas). (es necesario mostrar un mensaje con el número de la factura mayor, otro con menor y si no tiene factura, un mensaje indicándolo).

Este ejercicio necesito una función que a través de facturas me diga los nombres y apellidos de los clientes para luego meterlo en un cursor que lo valla recogiendo a través del numero de la factura pero me da un error y no encuentro cual es.

***Mi código :*** Compila perfectamente pero a la hora de llamar a la función me falla

```
USE almacen;


DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS client $$
CREATE FUNCTION client(nfactura INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
BEGIN
    DECLARE nombCliencCompleto VARCHAR(150);
    SELECT CONCAT(nombreCli,' ',ap1,' ',ap2) INTO nombCliencCompleto FROM clientes,facturas WHERE nCliente=cod_cliente;
  
    RETURN nombCliencCompleto;
    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Llamo a la función con :*** Y aquí es cuando me salta el error

```
SELECT client(1);
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar mi codigo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi error estaba que el nombre de la función **client** no me lo permite no se el motivo le he cambiado el nombre a la función `nombcliente`  y ya me muestra el cliente de la factura 1

Otro error es que la tabla **factura** tengo una columna llamada **nFactura** por lo que lo tuve que cambiar el nombre del parámetro de la función para que no se confundieran

```
USE almacen;


DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS nombcliente $$
CREATE FUNCTION nombcliente(factura INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(150) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE nombCliencCompleto VARCHAR(150);
    SELECT CONCAT(nombreCli,' ',ap1,' ',ap2) INTO nombCliencCompleto FROM clientes,facturas WHERE facturas.nCliente=clientes.cod_cliente and factura=facturas.nFactura;
  
    RETURN nombCliencCompleto;
    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Llamo a la función :**

```
SELECT nombcliente(1);
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar mi Solucion</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/222)

***Me devuelve :*** Ramon Gonzalez Tamudo